# White Screen of Death

Tags: plugins

I have been trying to resurrect my wordpress site after a plugin upgrade went bad.
I do not know which plugin caused the issue.

Things I have tried.

- Renaming plugins and themes folders
- define('WP_DEBUG', true); and define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
  These do not seem to produce any output or logs on the filesystem
- Removing all references to CACHE in wp-config
- define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '1024M');
- in /etc/php/7.2/fpm/pool.d/www.conf (php_admin_value[memory_limit] = 128M)

I am still getting a white screen with nothing in the page source. Also my mysql, nginx and php logs do not show any errors.

Any help so very much appreciated!

Comment: You need to look in your PHP error log to get the actual error message, are you sure you disabled all plugins? Have  you  confirmed the config file contains no PHP error messages? What about your theme? Have you made modifications to core WP files in` wp-admin` or  `wp-includes`?

Comment: Sometimes you can get a WSOD when the active theme is missing.

Comment: What happens if you add `define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true);` to `wp-config.php` ?